# inherited role task created but not running

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use an hierarchy of roles (technical role on specific object) and a usage role X granted with this technical role.
my schema dataprep is with access managed.

`grant usage on warehouse WH to role TWX;`
`grant ownership on all tasks in schema dataprep to role TX revoke current grants;`
`grant ownership on future tasks in schema dataprep to role TX revoke current grants;`
`grant role TWX to role X`
`grant role Tx to role X`

i have too fixed the privilege execute_task on account.

with role X, i created an task with success but i have an error when resuming this task:
Cannot execute task , USAGE privilege on the task's warehouse must be granted to owner role

So i use differents grant  directly on role X and it's work.

i don't understand. the inheriting does not work for task execution ? can you explain the problem ?

thanks

Comment: which role is schema onwer?

Comment: i use a role sys_admin as owner  of schema and i have grant role X to role sys_admin.  i have access WH, schema etc ... in interactive mode.

Comment: i must add grant ownership for role X only and not TX to working my task. Yet, the role TX granted to the role X. For the ownership privilege, it's not work, isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

In managed access schemas (i.e. schemas created using the CREATE SCHEMA … WITH MANAGED ACCESS syntax), only the schema owner (i.e. the role with the OWNERSHIP privilege on the schema) can grant or revoke privileges on future objects in the schema.

More details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html#security-privileges-required-to-manage-future-grants

Comment: i don't have problem of access in interactive mode. i can create task, write table etc .. in the schema.